# React Redux: How to create state objects based on data that will change and how to update individual elements within each object

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, redux, state, manpage

Problem: I don't know how to organise my state to easily make changes to it. It is retrieved as an array of objects. it is mapped in components but making updates to individual elements and then figuring out how to update these in the database.

The application set up: React Redux Saga Node Express Postgres

fetch call retrieves an array of objects (user details), this is added to a state object and then this array is used to map a component with 4 inputs. I want to be able to change any element of any object and have it update to the state. I would then add a fetch to update any changes to the original data to the database. I am looking for information such as websites, books, courses etc that would help to build a foundation so I could solve this issue.

for reference below are sections of my code;

data

```
userData: Array(4)
0: {firstname: "shane", surname: "smith", email: "shanesmith@gmail.com", auth: false}
1: {firstname: "Sahne", surname: "Smith", email: "shane@gmail.com", auth: false}
etc....
```

Reducer

```
    FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_START,
    FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_FAILURE,
    UPDATE_ADMIN_USER_DATA,
} from "../types/types";

// import utility functions

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isFetching: false,
    userData: [],
    errorMessage: null,
};

const adminReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_START:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
            };
        case FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                userData: action.payload.user[0],
            };
        case FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                errorMessage: action.payload,
            };
        case UPDATE_ADMIN_USER_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                userData: [haven't found a silution],
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default adminReducer;
```

Action

```
import {
    FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_START,
    FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_FAILURE,
    UPDATE_ADMIN_USER_DATA,
} from "../types/types";

export const fetchAdminPageStart = () => ({
    type: FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_START,
});

export const fetchAdminPageSuccess = (data) => ({
    type: FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_SUCCESS,
    payload: data,
});

export const fetchAdminPageFailure = (errorMessage) => ({
    type: FETCH_ADMIN_PAGE_FAILURE,
    payload: errorMessage,
});

export const updataAdminUserData = (data) => ({
    type: UPDATE_ADMIN_USER_DATA,
    payload: data,
});
```

Component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// Material Ui Componnents
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";

//Components
import UserDetailsComponent from "../../components/container-withheader/users-details.component";
// Styled Components
import { StyledTabs } from "./admin-page.styles";
// Selectors
import { selectAdminPageUserData } from "../../redux/admin-page/admin-page.selectors";
// Actions
import { updataAdminUserData } from "../../redux/admin-page/admin-page.actions";

const AdminPageComponent = ({ userDetails, updataAdminUserData }) => {
    useEffect(() => {}, []);

    // const [userData, setUserData] = useState({ users: userDetailData });

    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);

    const handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setSelectedTab(newValue);
    };

    const handleChangeData = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.name);
        return updataAdminUserData(event.target);
    };

    const handleToggleChange = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target);
        return updataAdminUserData(event.target);
    };

    const tabArray = ["Users", "Options"];
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar position='static' color='default'>
                <StyledTabs
                    value={selectedTab}
                    onChange={handleTabChange}
                    variant='scrollable'
                    scrollButtons='auto'
                    aria-label='scrollable auto tabs example'
                >
                    {tabArray.map((tab, i) => (
                        <Tab label={tab} key={i} />
                    ))}
                </StyledTabs>
            </AppBar>

            {selectedTab === 0 && (
                <UserDetailsComponent
                    userData={userDetails}
                    handleChangeData={handleChangeData}
                    handleToggleChange={handleToggleChange}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

AdminPageComponent.propTypes = {
    userDetails: PropTypes.object,
    updataAdminUserData: PropTypes.func,
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    userDetails: selectAdminPageUserData,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    updataAdminUserData: (data) => dispatch(updataAdminUserData(data)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdminPageComponent);
```

Component Child of above

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// Styled Components
import {
    StyledToolBar,
    GridContainer,
    RightElement,
    StyledTextField,
    StyledSwitch,
} from "./users-details.styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
}));

const UserDetailsComponent = ({
    userData,
    handleChangeData,
    handleToggleChange,
}) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [edit, setEdit] = useState({
        editUser: true,
    });
    const handleEditChange = (event) => {
        setEdit({ ...edit, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <br></br>
            <StyledToolBar elevation={3}>
                <GridContainer>
                    <RightElement>
                        <FormControlLabel
                            control={
                                <Switch
                                    checked={edit.editUser}
                                    onChange={handleEditChange}
                                    name='editUser'
                                />
                            }
                            label='Edit User'
                        />
                    </RightElement>
                </GridContainer>
            </StyledToolBar>
            <br></br>
            <Paper styles={{ paddingTop: "2rem" }} elevation={3}>
                <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete='on'>
                    {userData.map((user, i) => (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <StyledTextField
                                name={Number(i)}
                                title={"Enter first name here"}
                                alt={"firstname"}
                                id={`firstname`}
                                input={`firstname`}
                                onChange={handleChangeData}
                                disabled={edit.editUser}
                                label='First Name'
                                value={user.firstname}
                                variant='outlined'
                            />
                            <StyledTextField
                                name={Number(i)}
                                id={"surname"}
                                disabled={edit.editUser}
                                label='Surame'
                                value={user.surname}
                                variant='outlined'
                            />
                            <StyledTextField
                                name={Number(i)}
                                id={"email"}
                                disabled={edit.editUser}
                                label='Email'
                                value={user.email}
                                variant='outlined'
                            />
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <FormControlLabel
                                    control={
                                        <StyledSwitch
                                            disabled={edit.editUser}
                                            checked={user.auth}
                                            onChange={handleToggleChange}
                                            name={Number(i)}
                                            id={"auth"}
                                        />
                                    }
                                    label='Has Administration Access'
                                />
                            </React.Fragment>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </form>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
};

export default UserDetailsComponent;
```

As you can see I need to also find a better way to pass information in the event to differentiate each pice of state I wish to modify.

I don't know if I should modify the array into another type of object, how do I then map the users if I do so. What are best practices for this issue.

Ultimately I just want to learn or be pointed in the direction of information that would help me move past this problem. Any assistance if greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - converted to object, used multiple values in name then split into array.